# Experimenting with Provide/Inject API in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to experiment with Provide/Inject in Vue 3. The goal is to get rid of prop drilling by utilizing Provide/Inject API.

Let's consider having the following example:

```
App 
  |
  |_ _ CatsCollection 
             |
             |_ _ FavoriteCat
             |_ _ FavoriteCat
```

A `config` object is passed down from `App` to `FavoriteCat` passing through `CatsCollection`.

By using props to pass down the data, the hook `beforeUpdate()` fires on both components `CatsCollection` and `FavoriteCat`.

Now, I switch to using Provide/Inject. My initial thoughts are that the `beforeUpdate()` inside the `CatsCollection` component should not run. This component now receives no props. The FavoriteCat is using inject to retrieve the `config` object.

However, the `beforeUpdate()` hook is still running for the `CatsCollection`. Meaning that this component (middle component) is still re-rendering. Doesn't this defeat the purpose?

Am I missing anything?

I have a running sample here for reference.

https://vue3-prop-drilling-provide-inject.stackblitz.io

And I really appreciate your feedback.

Best,
Bill

Comment: I've responded to your post on the Vue Forum: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/experimenting-with-provide-inject-in-vue-3/106144. I believe it's a bug with `watch`, not directly related to `provide`/`inject`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2521